# Is there a way to ignore test/conftest.py in py.test?

Tags: pytest

Without moving any code around (I realise I could refactor but for various reasons that is inconvenient), is there a way to call py.test whilst ignoring conftest.py?

I'd thought:

```
py.test -p no:pytestconfig
```

might work, but it seems like it doesn't.

Answer (score 28):

Use:

```
py.test --noconftest
```

According to py.test --help:

> --noconftest          Don't load any conftest.py files.

Answer (score 10):

Sure. 
Use `pytest --trace-config` and find the conftest.py you don't want to load.
Then use `-p no:<path>/conftest.py` to tell pytest to not use it.

For example, if the conftest.py file is in the current directory this works (if using bash, of course):

`pytest -p no:$(pwd)/conftest.py`

Answer (score 1):

According py.test [issue 82](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/82)

Maybe

`py.test --confcutdir`

may helps.

Answer (score 1):

On one hand, `conftest.py` cannot be ignored or renamed, see https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1569#issuecomment-221790555 for details on the why.

On the other hand, as described in that link, you can make a module (it could be just renaming `conftest.py` to `whatever_name_you_like.py`, or it could be a much more sophisticated module: your choice). And then create a `conftest.py` which contains simply

`pytest_plugins= ['whatever_name_you_like']`

At that point you can ignore it by invoking `py.test` with the `-p no:whatever_name_you_like`

Note that being these module names, none has the `.py` extension, but the file itself.